# Deployment of Translations

Tags: translation, workbench, deployment

**Context:**

I have been working on translating a Salesforce org using its Translation Workbench for a few days, and I finally found myself pleased with the translations I did. For your information, the translation was done was from PT_BR to EN_US (that is, Portuguese from Brazil to English from United States).

So far so good, I had some initial issues with describing them in the package.xml used by Ant to retrieve from my development org to deploy to the testing org. I figured out I had to put not only the `CustomLabel` tag, but also the `Translations` tag. Not very happy, but at least I got the pretty en_US.translation file in my directory now.

**Issue:**

Now I face the following issue: my deployment does not deploy the translations. I have the Translations and CustomLabel tags in my package.xml, and they simply don't work. One thing I noticed, though, was that the name of the app I'm trying to deploy was translated ("*Minha Aplicação*" > "*My Application*"), but everything else (custom fields, tabs) wasn't translated.

I already changed my profile's language to English in the target org, and the parts of the System that are Salesforce-defaults are translated (buttons like Setup, Develop, etc).

Does anyone know what to do in this case? Will I have to translate everything again in the target org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always seems like the answer comes after I ask about my issue somewhere. This time, I figured out I was missing the tag `CustomObjectTranslation` in package.xml. `Translations` seems to get some fields on the default objects, but custom fields and custom objects have different files for translations, inside a folder called *objectTranslations*.

Comment: Would it be possible to post the final package.xml you used? I'm having a similar issue, but CustomObjectTranslation does not seem to take the stuff I did in Translation Workbench, but only Rename Tabs and Labels...

Comment: I'm sorry Robin, but I don't have the files anymore! May I suggest taking a look at the Metadata API Developer Guide that talks about the CustomObjectTranslation and Translations objects? If I'm not mistaken, at least one of those has a xml example.

Comment: Would you mind taking at look at [my question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120455/how-to-retrieve-translations-using-metadata-api)?

Answer (score 2):

Here a sample file for deploying **Translations** (German) of some **Standard and Custom Objects with all its fields**:

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <members>Case</members>
    <members>CustomerRequest__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>

<types>
    <members>Account-de</members>
    <members>Contact-de</members>
    <members>Case-de</members>
    <members>CustomerRequest__c-de</members>
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>

<version>34.0</version>
```

Here a sample file for deploying **Translations** (German) of **Custom Applications, Custom Labels, Custom Buttons and Custom Tabs**:

```
<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomApplication</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomLabels</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomTab</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
    <name>Translations</name>
</types>
```